# Spacing placholder

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

how can i leave the placholder when start typeing and just extends forward

like when i type 100 space and INX

100 INX

so that when i type 100. INX move forward  and full input becomes

100 INX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Extend placeholder forward</h1>

  <input type="text" id="left" name="left" oninput="right.value = left.value; return true;" placeholder="INX"/>
  <input type="text" id="right" name="right" oninput="left.value = right.value; return true;" placeholder="INX" disabled />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Suggest you move it out of being a placeholder, eg `<input ...><span>INX</span>`

Comment: You can't do that directly - the _purpose_ of a placeholder is to disappear, as soon as something gets typed into the field.

Comment: The suggested `<input ...><span>INX</span>` would not get you the effect of the (fake) placeholder "following" the entered text though. You would either have to measure the width of the current text content and position the placeholder accordingly (could get complex, especially if the text runs wider than the width of the input field, when it won't start from the left any more) [...]

Comment: [...] - or replace the input with a span with `contenteditable` maybe, that would automatically run as wide as its text content demands. (You would have to grab the entered text and put it into a hidden field then, in case you wanted to submit it normally with a form.) Then the "placeholder" could follow in normal flow.

Comment: Or, a bit easier perhaps to have the INX "static" behind a fixe-width input field, and align the text content of that input to the right ...? Not _exactly_ matching the initial demand, but a potential trade-off in complexity ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't modify the behavior of a native placeholder.

Sort of hacky workaround with positioning, pseudo elements, and css variables:

```js
document.querySelector('#left').addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.parentElement.style.setProperty('--val', "'"+this.value+"'");
  document.querySelector('#right').value = this.value ? this.value + ' INX' : '';
});
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  --val: '';
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#div1::after {
  content: var(--val) ' INX';
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#left, #right {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  caret-color: black;
}

#left {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>Extend placeholder forward</h1>

<div id="div1"><input type="text" id="left" name="left" maxlength="18" /></div>
<div id="div2"><input type="text" id="right" name="right" placeholder="INX" disabled /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to do things with an input element - you can't attach pseudo elements for example.

Taking a slightly different approach, if instead of input you use a contenteditable div you can attach an after element with the INX as content and it will move along ahead of the actual input as the user types:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  padding: 5px;
}

div::after {
  content: ' INX';
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable></div>
```